# How to clear color matplotlib in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working with matplotlib and I want to resize matplot to remove while color.

My Image:

[image]

My code:

```
root.title("Raspberrypi")
root.overrideredirect(False)
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

#set window color
root.configure(bg='#80D5CF')

mlx_shape = (24, 32)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))  # start figure
fig.canvas.toolbar_visible = False

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

fig.subplots_adjust(0.05, 0.05, 0.95, 0.95)  # get rid of unnecessary paddin

chart_type = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
chart_type.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="both", padx= 20)

therm1 = ax.imshow(np.zeros(mlx_interp_shape), interpolation='none',
                   cmap=plt.cm.bwr, vmin=25, vmax=45)  # preemptive image

fig.canvas.draw()  # draw figure to copy background
ax_background = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)
```

Comment: Seems to be a `fill` issue, try to remove `fill="both"` from `pack` options.